# Azure DevOps extensions - what language can I use?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I want to develop a DevOps hub plugin that gets work item details and generates a PDF.

I have viewed the samples that all seem to use typescript: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/samples-overview?view=azure-devops.

I'm having trouble understanding the context that the code runs in, does it run on the server or in the browser? I know I need to use a web server as I have made a test hub plug in and is running from my local web server.

I would prefer to be able to use server side C# ASP.NET, is this possible or do we have to use a client side language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want to do it.

The DevOps extension itself is only on client side and is Javascript/Typescript. So, if you are developing say a custom control for the work item form, that's all you can use. But it is hosted within Azure DevOps itself.

If your hub shows an external page, you can do whatever you want. But you have to host all that content yourself.

For your example I would not use an external site. It can all be done in the browser. In fact I made a (private) extension that does something very similar.